# Why does assigning more values than the number of variables not give an error?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

I assigned values to less number of variables:

```
a, b ,c= 2, 3,4,5
```

Why does that not show an error?

Comment: This feature which can come in handy and many more are why trying to get away without unit tests in Ruby is a really bad idea.

Comment: thanks @TonyHopkinson early times ruby

Comment: I moved over about two years ago from C#. Linq, lambdas and closures help, but it's a serious head switch. I really enjoy the language though, and it changed the way I approach problems in C# as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple Assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)

> If you have more values on the right hand side of the assignment than variables on the left hand side the extra values are ignored. You can use `*` to gather extra values on the right-hand side of the assignment. The `*` can appear anywhere on the left-hand side. But you may only use one `*` in an *assignment*.

Comment: maybe that is the way the language is designed ! but it should be thrown error know ?

Comment: @utility No.. Because they designed this way.